# How can i make box with no white space in webpage with css?

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

The margins from left and right in web page shows white space which is the color of the background , i want to remove it ,how?

this is my css:

```
.box-one {
    background-color: #c8d6e5;
    height: 300px;
    width:200;
    margin-top: 1200px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 29px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `font-size: 0` to remove all white spaces, including text.

But if you're looking to maintain text, try `padding: 0`.

Comment: i mean the margins from left and right in web page shows white space which is the color of the background , i want to remove it

Comment: Mmm, I think you should remove `width:200` if you're trying to create a box with the size just of the text inside it. `width:200` will force the box size to 200px, which can create blank spaces in your box.

Answer (score 0):

```
width:auto;
```

And remove the margin left and right and add padding instead!